# Header image causing huge gap

Tags: php, html, css

I've managed to get an image I made to appear in the header of my woostore theme next to the default header logo, however a great big gap has appeared between the image and the top of the page, which I think is actually being caused by the logo somehow. I'm not good at coding just was a little trial and error, so could anyone take a look please and advise me on what to do?

Here's the specific header code:

```
<?php } ?>

 <div id="header" class="col-full">

 <div id="logo">
 <div id="headbanner" style="height:500px; width:186px; position:relative; top:500px; left:275px;">
 <img src="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Store-header-Image.png" alt="Official Store" /></div>
```

and the site address: http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/

Comment: Something is giving your `#headbanner` element a height of 500px, therefore stretching the height of the header element.

You can use developer tools on Chrome to inspect the styles of each element.

Comment: Change `<div id="headbanner" style="height:500px; width:186px; position:relative; top:500px; left:275px;">` to `<div id="headbanner" style="height:500px; width:186px; position:relative; top:0px; left:275px;">` or any other pixel value you want. Looks like that's the problem when viewing your source.

Comment: To add, you'll have to do the same for `http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Logo.png` or make both images/logos as one.

Answer (score 0):

In the #headbanner just give float remove other.

```
#headbanner{float:right;}
#search-top{float:right; clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you currently have.

```
#headerbanner{
  height: 500px;
  width: 186px;
  position: relative;
  top: 500px;
  left: 275px;
}
```

Change this to:

```
#headerbanner{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 198px;
}
```

**Give the div with the id "Logo" 100% width.**

```
<div id="logo" style="&nbsp; &nbsp; width: 100%;">                                  
</div>
```

**Also you should reorder your logo and the header banner like so.**

```
<a href="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/" title="" style="float: left;"><img src="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Logo.png" alt="Aggidukes Official Store"></a>
<div id="headbanner" style="float: left; margin: 0 0 0 198px;"><img src="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Store-header-Image.png" alt="Official Store"></div>
```

The link wrapping the logo should "float:left;"

Final result should look like

```
<div id="header" class="col-full">
  <div id="logo" style="width: 100%;"> <a href="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/" title="" style="float: left;"> <img src="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Logo.png" alt="Aggidukes Official Store"></a>
    <div id="headbanner" style="float: left;  margin: 0 0 0 198px;"> <img src="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Store-header-Image.png" alt="Official Store"></div>
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/">Aggidukes Official Store</a></h1>
    <span class="site-description"></span> </div>
  <!-- /#logo -->
  <div id="search-top">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store">
      <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
      <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" class="field s" placeholder="Search">
      <input type="image" class="submit btn" name="submit" value="Search" src="http://aggidukes.co.uk/store/wp-content/themes/woostore/images/ico-search.png">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
    </form>
    <div class="fix"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.search-top --> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million gonna try it now and post my results shortly